# Parsing list with json structure and match values in python

Tags: python, json

I have the following code which gives the city based on IP:

```
RANGES = {
        'Paris': [
            {'start': '10.10.0.0', 'end': '10.10.255.255'},
            {'start': '192.168.1.0', 'end': '192.168.1.255'},
        ],
        'NYC': [
            {'start': '10.12.0.0', 'end': '10.12.255.255'},
            {'start': '172.16.10.0', 'end': '172.16.11.255'},
            {'start': '192.168.2.0', 'end': '192.168.2.255'},
        ]
    }

def get_city(self, ip):
        print 'Here'
        for city, ipranges in self.RANGES.items():
            for iprange in ipranges:
                if ip >= iprange['start'] and ip <= iprange['end']:
                    return city
```

I have another variable:

```
RECORDS = [
        {'user_id': 1, 'created_at': '2017-01-01T10:00:00', 'status': 'paying'},
        {'user_id': 1, 'created_at': '2017-03-01T19:00:00', 'status': 'paying'},
        {'user_id': 1, 'created_at': '2017-02-01T12:00:00', 'status': 'cancelled'},
        {'user_id': 3, 'created_at': '2017-10-01T10:00:00', 'status': 'paying'},
        {'user_id': 3, 'created_at': '2016-02-01T05:00:00', 'status': 'cancelled'},
    ]
```

For which I'm trying to implement this function:

```
 def get_status(self, user_id, date): //should return the status
```

I'm not sure how to parse the list -> match the values -> return the status for the matching combination of `created_at` and `user_id`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it :

```
def get_status(user_id, date):
    for i,ele in enumerate(RECORDS): 
        if ele['user_id']==user_id and ele['created_at']==date: 
            return ele['status']

print(get_status(1, '2017-02-01T12:00:00'))
#'cancelled'
```

Here, we are going through the `list` and using the `dict` element in it to match its keys (`user_id` and `created_at`) and check if the values match with the required values. Ofcourse, make sure that the `RECORDS` value should be available in the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this

```
>>> def get_status(user_id, date):
    for rec in RECORDS:
        if rec['user_id'] == user_id and rec['created_at'] == date:
            return rec['status']
>>> get_status(1, '2017-01-01T10:00:00')
'paying'
>>>
```